# SvelteKit and Swiper 6.8.1: how to use slideTo(index)

Tags: svelte, swiper.js, sveltekit

Slider 6.8.1 works well with SvelteKit. I would like to be able to select a certain slide also by program. This is apparently possible with `swiper.slideTo(index, speed)`.

`swiper` is created for example like this:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  speed: 400,
  spaceBetween: 100,
});
```

However, SvelteKit requires Swiper to be imported like this:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte';
```

But then `new Swiper` returns the error message

`__vite_ssr_import_1__.default is not a constructor`

This is quite understandable, but how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you import `Swiper` from `'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte'` then it's no more the class but the svelte component that you will use in your template like:

```html
  <Swiper>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    ...
  </Swiper>
```

In your case you need both the component and the class that you will initialise during the component mount:

```js
  import SwiperComponent from "swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte";
  import { Swiper } from "swiper";
```

You can then store the `Swiper` instance in a reactive variable like in this example:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  import SwiperComponent from "swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte";
  import SwiperSlide from "swiper/esm/svelte/swiper-slide.svelte";
  import { Swiper } from "swiper";
  import "swiper/swiper.scss";

  let swiper = null;

  onMount(() => {

    // initialise the swiper
    swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
      loop: true
    });

    // go to slide 6 after one second
    setTimeout(() => {
      swiper.slideTo(6, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>

<SwiperComponent>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    ...
</SwiperComponent>
```

[image: Edit damp-tdd-tz70n]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and interesting explanations. This is apparently a solution for Svelte. But whenIi try the program with SvelteKit, I get again 

"Error: <SwiperComponent> is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules."

Probably something like

"import Swiper from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte';" and
"import SwiperSlide from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper-slide.svelte';"

is necessary, but I haven't found out how.

Comment: I see will try to create a sveltekit POC.

Comment: @MartinWeissenboeck You are right the svelte component should be imported from `"swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte"`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, after the change the example works. New problem: I want to use "Navigation" and "Pagination". I tried it in several places, but without success.

Comment: And another problem: I added a button to control slide 3:

"<button on:click={()=>swiper.slideTo(3,1500)}>Slide 3</button>".

But this button only works when slide 0 is active. Strange!

Comment: @MartinWeissenboeck Would be nice to open a new question for this one with your updated code base and finish this one  Just share the link as a comment.

Comment: Maybe swiper 7.0 is the solution. I'll try it.